# Why Google Forms does not return user response on formSubmit?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have created a sample google form, and defined a function like below:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log('Inside function');
  Logger.log('Emailing data row ->');

  var itemResponses = e.getItemResponses();
  var email = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  Logger.log(itemResponses);
}
```

In `Edit-> Current project's triggers` I have added the function to be called on form submit:

[image]

In `My Executions` section I see the error below:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getItemResponses" of undefined. at onSubmit(Code:7)

Why is it like that? How should I capture form fields? Is there something wrong with my code, or some permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there was a bug in `Google Forms` which is being happened only on newly created forms:

- [Google forms script on form submit - event does not have FormResponse](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/118921815)

2 workarounds are suggested:

> 1) Include a call to FormApp somewhere in the code, even in a comment.
>   For example:
>
> // FormApp.getActiveForm();
>
> 2) Add the scope to your Apps Script manifest file, as per these
>   instructions:
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes
>
> The scope to add is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms"
>
> Once you've completed either of those two options, re-authorize your
>   script. You can do this be running any function in the script editor.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and @ALH's solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the getItemResponses() method on the response property of the e object, not directly on the e object.

Replace:

```
  var itemResponses = e.getItemResponses();
```

With:

```
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
```

Comment: This was correct, but again problem did not get solved. There seems a bug in `Google Form`